# Update fragments - by swipe from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, refresh

I have main_activity with fragments. Main Activity contains swiperefreshlayout overlaying viewerpager. After swiping new data is downloaded, now I want to refresh it on every fragment. How can I achieve that?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

object simple_object;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout1);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh items
            refreshItems(); //refreshing simple object
        }
    });

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new main_tab1(simple_object), "Tab1");
    adapter.addFragment(new main_tab2(simple_object), "Tab2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you wanna update all fragments' content or only the fragment currently displayed?

Comment: The best option would be to update all fragments.

Comment: Now I noticed that adding swiperefresh isn't also so easy for tablyout.